# ListView loses scroll position when using InheritedWidget in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, inherited-widget

After adding InheritedWidget to app I recognize that ListView loses scroll position (selected item index) when I come back to list from details screen using Pop().

I know that widget can be rebuild any time but maybe someone can suggest solution without handling cache manually.

P.S.
Scroll position was fine before implementing InheritedWidget

Comment: We lack information. Maybe insert some code to help us reproduce the error

Comment: The problem in this case was in wrong way to implementing GlobalKey for some widgets inside ListView. So it wasn't InheritedWidget's problem

Answer (score 22, accepted):

no any code so a shot in the dark

try to add 'key'
like this

```
ListView(
   key: const PageStorageKey<String>('some unique text'),
   //other parameters
);
```